# AS3 applying a Format via function

Tags: actionscript-3, format, handle

I am trying to write a function that applies TextFormats to the TextFields they belong to.
The problem is, that i don't manage it to get it into the right "Form"(if there is even a right form for this).

My function looks like this at the moment

```
function applyFormat(TextFild:String,Format:String,EmbFont:String,NameInJson:String){

//
//example:applyFormat("myTextField","myTextFormat","myFont","TextStuff")
//  
//myData=json object
//all textfields etc. already exist. Just anyone wants to ask if they've been already generated.

//at first i thought it could be as easy as this
this[Format].font=myData.NameInJson.Font //doesn't work obviously

//then I tried this method
this[Format].font=myData.this[NameInJson].Font //doesn't work either

//couldn't find a real solution for this on the internet...    
//how it should turn out in the end: myTextFormat.font=myData.TextStuff.Font
}
```

The related part of myData looks like this:

```
"TextStuff":
{
"Font":"Arial",
"Size" : "16",
"Bold" : "true",
"Color" : "0xFFFFFF"
}
```

do I need to change my Json file to make this possible?
am I overlooking a method to handle with this kind of variables/values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this[Format]` will look for a property on the class with the name Format. AFAIK the class has to be dynamic for this to work.

If you keep your `TextFormat` instances in an object in that class it will be easier to manage:

```
// this is a property in the class
private var _textFormats:Object = {};

// create and store text formats in the object
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
_textFormats["myTextFormat"] = textFormat;
```

Now assuming you get a JSON text string like this :

```
{
"TextStuff":{
    "Font":"Arial",
    "Size" : "16",
    "Bold" : "true",
    "Color" : "0xFFFFFF"
  }
}
```

The following should work with this call `applyFormat("myTextField","myTextFormat","myFont","TextStuff")`

```
function applyFormat(TextField:String, Format:String, EmbFont:String, NameInJson:String):void
{
    var myData:Object = JSON.parse(theJSonString);
    _textFormats[Format].font = myData[NameInJson].Font;
}
```

Comment: i slapped my forehead when i was reading this solution.
it's just so simple! why didn't I think of this? I feel so stupid now...
Anyway, thanks alot for your solution, it helped me out a lot!(would upvote if i had enough reputation...)